# Display list items horizontal in a menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, menu

i have a menu with bootstrap with my styles, but when I inserted my menu in bootstrap css style to make it collapsible and apply media queries, it shows vertical, i want to show horizontal, how can i do? I am apply `display inline` to all elements but it's still vertical... Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/AD8vB/2/

Comment: add this to your styles `ul#topnav li {float:left}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
#topnav li{float:left; list-style:none;}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/codingantGit/AD8vB/3/)**</kbd>